# duckdb SQL select result to JSON

Tags: python, sql, json, duckdb

Is there a way to convert the result of a `SELECT` query on a table directly to JSON without writing it to a file? Perhaps with the JSON extension of `duckdb`?

I could also use the python client, where I'd convert the result to a pandas dataframe and then to JSON, but I figured there should be a more direct way.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE weather (
      city    VARCHAR,
      temp_lo INTEGER, -- minimum temperature on a day
      temp_hi INTEGER, -- maximum temperature on a day
      prcp    REAL,
      date    DATE
  );
INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('San Francisco', 46, 50, 0.25, '1994-11-27');
INSERT INTO weather VALUES ('Vienna', -5, 35, 10, '2000-01-01');
```

An example query would be `"SELECT city, temp_hi FROM weather;"`, and the desired json would look like:

```
{"city": ["San Francisco", "Vienna"], "temp_hi": [50, 35]}
```

So to recap, I'm looking for way to create the desired JSON directly, without converting the result to a python object first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`list` aggregate function](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/aggregates) with a [`STRUCT`](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/struct). The latter can be defined using curly braces or `struct_pack`:

```
SELECT {city: list(city), temp_hi: list(temp_hi)}::JSON AS j FROM weather;
SELECT struct_pack(city := list(city), temp_hi := list(temp_hi))::JSON AS j FROM weather;
```

Both of them will produce the same result:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                           j                           │
│                         json                          │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"city":["San Francisco","Vienna"],"temp_hi":[50,35]} │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where are you writing the query and where are you expecting the output of the query.

- In case you are using the duckdb CLI tool, you can set "mode" before querying anything like this

  ```
  v0.9.2 3c695d7ba9
  D .mode json
  D SELECT city, temp_hi from weather;
  [{"city":"San Francisco","temp_hi":50},
  {"city":"Vienna","temp_hi":35}]
  ```
- If its using the Python client API, from check the source code, it appears it doesn't have implemented a JSON mode like the CLI tool does. It does have a `render_mode` [parameter but it only has 2 options](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/blob/28543c9782b3def06a3a17d164fc6dca720b5fbc/tools/pythonpkg/duckdb_python.cpp#L281C1-L284C23). You can test it by writing a query and passing the render_mode to the `show()` function. like `con.sql("SELECT city, temp_hi form weather").show(render_mode=1)`. You can just use the `fetchall()` which returns a tuple of the results

  Anyways if going with the Python route, why not use the conversion options? such as a pandas dataframe

  ```py
  import duckdb

  with duckdb.connect("weather.db") as con:
      result = con.sql("SELECT city, temp_hi from weather").df()
  weather = result.to_json(orient="records")
  print(weather)
  > [{"city":"San Francisco","temp_hi":50},{"city":"Vienna","temp_hi":35}]
  ```